# Expectation over vector coefficients defined in mixed deterministic-random protocol

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, expected-value

Let $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ a real vector,

We define the vector $\textbf{y} = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ following this protocol:

- We take a subset of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ of cardinal $n-l$, we denote this subset by $S_l$, $\forall i \in S_l: y_i = x_i$.

For the remaining $l$ elements of $\{1, \dots, n\}$: Let $a \in [-1,1]$, independently:

- $y_i = x_i$ with probability $\frac{1+a}{2}$
- $y_i = - x_i$ with probability $\frac{1-a}{2}$

We will say that $\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})$ if the vector $ \textbf{y}$ was generated following the protocol above.

My question is: What is $\underset{\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})}{\mathbb{E}}[ \underset{i \in S}{\prod} y_i ]$ for some subset $S \subseteq [n]$

My attempt:

$\underset{\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})}{\mathbb{E}}[ \underset{i \in S}{\prod} y_i ] = \underset{i \in S}{\prod} \underset{\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})}{\mathbb{E}}[  y_i ]$ (independence)

There's $\binom{l}{|S|}$ ways to choose $|S| -l$ elements from the set $|S|$

Hence, the expectation is:
$\underset{\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})}{\mathbb{E}}[ \underset{i \in S}{\prod} y_i ] = \underset{i \in S}{\prod} (  \binom{l}{|S|} x_i + \frac{1+a}{2} x_i - \frac{1-a}{2} x_i  )$

And this gives:
$\underset{\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_{a,l}(\textbf{x})}{\mathbb{E}}[ \underset{i \in S}{\prod} y_i ] = ( \binom{l}{|S| + a} + a)^{|S|} \underset{i \in S}{\prod} x_i $

However, I'm not sure about the first part of the expectation ($\binom{l}{|S|} x_i$). It seems like the protocol is divided into a deterministic way of fixing $n-l$ elements of the vector $\textbf{x}$ and the other part is random. How would the expectation be expressed in this case ?

Comment: Is the choice of $S_l$ random or is it fixed?

Comment: The choice of $S_l$ is fixed

Comment: Then, I don't understand why you want to choose $\vert S\vert - \ell$ elements from $\vert S\vert$... Could you explain?

Comment: We don't know the elements $i \in S$ for which $x_i$ is maintained fixed (first step of the protocol). So it's not choosing $|S|-l$ elements but it's $|S|-j$ elements where $j \leq l$. I know that my solution is false, it's just the way I think of it, I'm sure there's a way to solve it

Comment: But you said that the choice of $S_l$ is fixed. So we do know which elements are kept fixed in $S$, namely the elements in $S\cap S_l$...

Comment: @MushuNrek sorry what do you mean by $S_l$? On your first comment I thought $S_l$ means $S$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148030/discussion-between-mushu-nrek-and-ayoubayjx).